# Google Calendar API - get all meeting invites for a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

Does Google Calendar API provide an endpoint for getting all of the meeting invites that a given user has yet to respond to? I'm familiar with the `responseStatus` field in the Event API so one way I imagine doing this is simply looking through all events on the calendar for which `responseStatus == 'needsAction'` but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to [get the Event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) and loop through the attendees to check the status. You can give that a [try here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it), so you can immediately see the results.